# how to print a self implemented stack?

Tags: java, stack

I'm using a self implemented stack to delete and add characters in order to get a final result (I'm kind of decoding a string).

Example: The input 'hello-' has to give 'hell'. The '-' deletes the character before it.

Current output - 'hellol'

The only requirement is that I have to use a self implemented stack. Do you guys have any suggestions? I appreciate your help!

```
 //this is my code for the stack
    public class MyStack{
       static int maxSize;
       static char[] stackArray;
       static int top;

       public MyStack(int s) {
          maxSize = s;
          stackArray = new char[maxSize];
          top = -1;
       }

    public boolean empty() {
        return (top == -1);
    }

    public void push(char item) {
        stackArray[++top] = item;

    }

    public char peek() {
        return stackArray[top];
    }

    public char pop() {
        return stackArray[top--];
    }
    }

    //this is in my main:
    for (char ch : password.toCharArray()){ //password is the input(hello-)
                if(Character.isLetter(ch) || Character.isDigit(ch)){
                    theStack.push(ch);
                    System.out.println(theStack.peek());    
                    }

                if(ch == '-'){
                    theStack.pop();
                    System.out.println(theStack.peek());
                }
        }
```

Comment: So what is the question? How to print an array?

Comment: Does your pop method work the way it intends to?

Comment: @Vollmilchbb yes it does, as you can see (by the way I used to print it) 'hello-' gives 'hellol'. The last 'l' is from the print statement in my second if statement. The 'l' is after the pop the last element in my stack.

Comment: But the question is already answered by @Joop Eggen  and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `toString` of `MyStack`:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MyStack: " + new String(stackArray, 0, top + 1):
}
```

Now you can do

```
System.out.println(theStack);
```

The fields should not be `static`. With `static` the fields exist once for the entire class. Without the fields exist for every stack object.

```
private int maxSize;
private char[] stackArray;
private int top;
```

Comment: @maria In that case you should mark the answer as accepted aswer. This way everyone else knows, that the question is already answered =) And you don't need to repost the answer ;)

Comment: @MeinName Haha im feeling like the noob I am, I'm new to this. How do I do that ..XD